# Describe solutions to a Diophantine Equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What does it mean to describe all the solutions to a Diophantine equation? Is it the same as simply finding the solution/general solution?

Comment: Its a general statement, but usually implies there is a succinct way of presenting it.

Comment: Would that then be the general solution where you can express x and y in terms of n?

Comment: That is typical.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that describing all the solutions is to put a general equation to easily find them. The following fact first characterizes whether a given Diophantine equation is solvable or not.

> For any Diophantine equation of the form $ax+by=c$, it is solvable if and only if $gcd(a,b)$ divides $c$.

If that holds on a given equation, then you have to find at least one solution. Usually, guessing will work. However, if it does not, you can use the [extended euclidean algorithm](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/euclid.html) to do so. After finding a solution ($x_0$,$y_0$), the general form for all solutions can be derived as follows:

$$x = x_0 +\frac{b}{g}t, \qquad g = gcd(a,b)$$
$$y = y_0 -\frac{a}{g}t, \qquad g = gcd(a,b)$$